# CountDownTimer inside Service is starts again when app killed

Tags: android

I have a service in which i have a CountDownTimer.When app runs everything is fine but when i kill the app the service starts the timer from beginning in background.
why this happening.Service is also killed if i create it like given link.

http://androidyou.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-intentservice-how-to-write.html

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: when app is killed call CountDownTimer.stop();

Comment: ok,i am editting my question..

Comment: Is it extending `IntentService` or `Service` class? What is your `onStartCommand ` method returning?

Comment: @Pr38y it is extending Service

Comment: i am doing onCreate()

Comment: Service restarts based on returned int from `onStartCommand` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)